# SSL Android - AsyncHttpClient

Tags: android, security, ssl, certificate, asynchttpclient

I am building an android app which is connecting to a server and retrieving data. First I got to choose whether I will be using AsynchTask (with HttoClient) or AsynchHttpClient, and i chose AsynchHttpClient. Now, actually everything is working fine, but today, when I was debugging something else, I noticed that the debugger throws a warning when I am sending/retrieving data(I am doing everything over https). The debugger says something like `Beware! using the fix is insecure, as it doesn't verify SSL certificates`. I was doing some digging, and I found this message inside of the AsynchHttpClient class, the actual part where it is comming from is here:

```
private static SchemeRegistry getDefaultSchemeRegistry(boolean fixNoHttpResponseException, int httpPort, int httpsPort) {
    if (fixNoHttpResponseException) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Beware! Using the fix is insecure, as it doesn't verify SSL certificates.");
    }

    if (httpPort < 1) {
        httpPort = 80;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Invalid HTTP port number specified, defaulting to 80");
    }

    if (httpsPort < 1) {
        httpsPort = 443;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Invalid HTTPS port number specified, defaulting to 443");
    }
```

I am not quite sure which fix is meant. And yes i almost forgot, I read that it may be because I am using self signed certificates (for testing), but before i release something which isn't secure I thought I ask here if someone else knows what exactly this message means

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something wrong with your cetificates ?
I use this method to add my certificates in Android projects.

```
    public static SSLContext getFactory() throws Exception {
    KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

    InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myfile);

    try {
        // Initialisation de notre keystore. On entre le mot de passe (storepass)
        trusted.load(in, "mypassword".toCharArray());
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }


    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
    tmf.init(trusted);

    SSLContext ssl_context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    ssl_context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    return ssl_context;
}
```

Comment: Actually I call this method when I create my socket from SocketIO  [https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) 
See my code : `SocketIO.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(getFactory());
this.socket = new SocketIO();
socket.connect(url, this);
SocketIO.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(getFactory());
`